# Colspan not merging the columns in Extjs Table Layout

Tags: extjs, tablelayout

I am trying to design a layout like the one shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJRa7.png). I tried the following code

```js
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            xtype: 'panel',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            defaults: {
          // applied to each contained panel
           bodyStyle: 'padding:20px'
      },
            items: [{
                // This is the component A in layout image
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Text-1'
            },{
                // This is the component B in layout image
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Text-2'
            },{
                // This is the component C in layout image
                xtype: 'textareafield',
                fieldLabel: 'TextArea-1',
                colspan: 2
            }],
            layout: {
                type: 'table',
                columns: 2,
                align:'stretch'
                
            },
        });
    }
});
```

But I'm not able to make the `colspan` work for the `textarea` field. The output of the above code looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/larRl.png).

Can anyone please help me to make this one work?

PS: I tried emulating the table layout by creating a container - Hbox layout combination. That one works. But I still need to get this one working.

Comment: Did you try using `width` in terms of percentage (width: '100%') because the problem here, i think, is that the textarea has a colspan of 2 but its width doesn't fit with the parent,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @qmat suggests, you need to assign a percentage width to your textareafield, in order to give it the full width. The `colspan` is working as intended, but the textarea uses its standart width.

```
{
    xtype: 'textareafield',
    fieldLabel: 'TextArea-1',
    width: "100%",  // <- gives the textarea the full width
    colspan: 2
}
```

The `align:'stretch'` config has no effect, it is not an actual config of the table layout.
See the [ExtJs 4.2.5 docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Table) and the working [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1at2).

Answer (score 1):

Hope This will work for you.

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        xtype: 'panel',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [{
            // This is the component A in layout image
            xtype: 'textfield',
            width:250,
            emptyText :'A'
          },{
            // This is the component B in layout image
            xtype: 'textfield',
            width:250,
            emptyText :'B'
           },{
            // This is the component C in layout image
            xtype: 'textfield',
            width:500,
            colspan:2,
            emptyText :'C'
         }],
        layout: {
            type: 'table',
            columns: 2

         },
    });
}});
```

You can check the link below and adjust width size as your requirment. Also add css if you want. 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1at3